# Hanoi Towers, working but not supposed to

Tags: java, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

So we have the classical Hanoi problem, Im just getting into this recursion thing, and its a doozie!
This is fully functioning, but I just don't understand how it could be! As I've understood it, for any n, it will print "from + " going to " + thru", this will happen as each time as n approaches 1. One would think that at n=1, the code would stop, and yet I get the printouts of the "thru + " going to " + to" (last printout). If n=1 is the terminating condition, how can I possibly get that last part of code "for free?".

I also expected the code to AT LEAST execute the last printout on every iteration, but no! Also, examples of this always include two recursive calls, but this works just fine with only one! What the hell is going on? How does this code execute, step by step? Have I misunderstood some basic fact about recursive methods? (Compiled on Eclipse compiler).

```
 public static void hanoi(char from, char to, char thru, int n) {
if (n==1) {
  System.out.println(from + " going to " + to);
}  else {
  System.out.println (from + " going to " + thru);
  hanoi(from, to, thru, n-1);
  System.out.println (thru + " going to " + to);
}
  }
```

Comment: Use break points and step through to see how it runs step by step.

Comment: Note that the default case usually has two recursive calls since if it's not one peg to move you move all but one to the `thru` using `to` as the new temporary, move the last peg `from` -> `to`, then recurse to move n-1 pegs from `thru` to `to` using `from` as temporary. Your implementation prints out `2n-1` lines while it should be `2^n-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have I misunderstood some basic fact about recursive methods?

It sounds like you have. You seem to have the impression that, even though you call into the method several times, the method only exits once. In truth, every time you hit this line:

```
System.out.println (from + " going to " + thru); <-- this line
hanoi(from, to, thru, n-1);
System.out.println (thru + " going to " + to);
```

... you must also hit the later line at some point after the recursive call completes:

```
System.out.println (from + " going to " + thru);
hanoi(from, to, thru, n-1);
System.out.println (thru + " going to " + to);   <-- this line
```

`n == 1` is the "terminating condition" in the sense that it does not make an additional recursive call. However, your "if" statement still has code in it:

```
if (n==1) {
  System.out.println(from + " going to " + to);
}
```

This code will be run as part of your final condition, but it will not call the `hanoi` method again. However, this is only the end of your recursive calls. For each other time the `hanoi` was called before this point, there is still a method call on the stack, and those method calls need to complete.

```
  System.out.println (from + " going to " + thru);
  hanoi(from, to, thru, n-1);   <-- if `n-1` here was `1`, you'd still have to 
                                    complete the following line.
  System.out.println (thru + " going to " + to);
```

Comment: Exactly! I expect that at n=1, it doesn't call the method again, and so, at n=1, I get my expected printout, but AFTER this printout i get an additional three printouts of `System.out.println (thru + " going to " + to);`, the last print out. How can this be? Why do I get additional printouts AFTER the recursion stops?

Comment: @user3504578: If `n` starts at a higher number, then by the time it gets to `n=1`, the method has already been called a number of times, hasn't it? Those method calls must complete after the `n=1` condition has been fulfilled.

Comment: Clear and concise! Very informative! Big Thanks!
Why didn't my programming lecturer tell me this? ^^

Answer (score 0):

> One would think that at n=1, the code would stop

This is where the false assumption lies. The Code does not stop. After executing
`System.out.println(from + " going to " + to);`
the method returns to the place where it was called. In your case. That is where `hanoi(from, to, thru, n-1);` is called.
It then continues until the end of the Method, therefore executing `System.out.println (thru + " going to " + to);`
Then again it returns to where it was called from and again continues until the end of the method body. This happens again and again until you reach your first call of `hanoi()`.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of Hanoi is to bring all the pieces from "from" to "to", sounds a little silly so let's call "from" "left" instead and "to" "right". For n = 1, you will just have to move the piece from the left side straight to the right side, to successfully finish the game by it's rules. This is why you get the text displayed, that you have mentioned.

For n = 2, you will have to move the top piece to the middle, the bigger piece at the bottom to the right and then the smaller piece from the middle to the right.

In pseudo-code, this reads as:

```
put the left piece to the middle

put the (other) left piece to the right 
(note that the roles of middle and right 
have been switched in the call of the 
hanoi-method and n is now 1, so no more calls)

put the middle piece to the right
```